# Printing xml DOM to a different directory through argparse using Python

Tags: python, xml, xslt, argparse

I am using the following code to parse xml files using xslt file.

```
import lxml.etree as ET

dom = ET.parse(xml_filename)
xslt = ET.parse(xsl_filename)
transform = ET.XSLT(xslt)
newdom = transform(dom)
print(ET.tostring(newdom, pretty_print=True))
```

The output currently gets generated in the same folder from where I am running the code....instead I would prefer to have it in a different folder.  I have tried using the following code:

```
import lxml.etree as ET
import argparse

ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-x", "--xmlfile", required=True, help="Path to the xmlfile")
ap.add_argument("-s", "--xslfile", required=True, help="Path to the xslfile")
ap.add_argument("-o", "--outputfolder", required=True, help="Path to the output files")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())

dom = ET.parse(args["xmlfile"])
xslt = ET.parse(args["xslfile"])
transform = ET.XSLT(xslt)
newdom = transform(dom)
print(ET.tostring(newdom, pretty_print=True))
```

But not sure how to integrate the args["outputfolder"] with print.  I tried the following:

```
print(ET.tostring(args["outputfolder"], newdom, pretty_print=TRUE))
print(ET.tostring(args["outputfolder"]/newdom, pretty_print=TRUE))
```

But this throws error.  I am using Python 2.7.6 on Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: There is a write method http://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree._ElementTree-class.html#write that takes a file name so I would try whether that simply allows a file name like `outputfolder/result.xml`.

Comment: @MartinHonnen  Thank you...since xslt prints multiple files I could not use the write method.  However, I have passed on the directory as an argument and used `os.chdir(args['outputfolder'])` before parsing the xmlfile.